# Racket - Given two natural numbers returns a list with all the numbers between a and b

Tags: list, numbers, racket

My question is:
Given two natural number returns a list with all the numbers between a and b

I tried this...

```
 * (define (intervalo l s)(cond [(= l s)(make-list l)]
                             [(< l s)]
                             [(> l s) empty ])) *
```

Comment: You can use the built-in `range` procedure for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "between a and b", do you mean including the lower bound only? including the upper bound only? Or including both?

Let's make a decision and consider a "half open interval" i.e. the lower bound is included but the upper bound isn't

First, think about what kind of Data the function takes in. As the question states — Natural numbers. Now let's formulate the problem as a brief sentence: "list of numbers from l to s, including l but excluding s"

Some examples:

- interval from 0 to 0 will yield an empty list
- interval from 1 to 3 will result in (list 1 2)
- interval from 3 to 1 is...? It's not valid.

[Refinement] An "assumption" needs be added: the upper bound should be less than or equal to the lower bound.

```
;; Nat Nat -> [Listof Nat]
;; all nats in [l, s) in order
;; ASUMPTION: (<= l s)
(define (intervalo l s)
  (if (= l s) '() (cons l (intervalo (+ l 1) s))))
```

- Racket already provides a `range` function which can be used as a reference implementation for testing.
- An explicit error message can be added for a `(> l s)` case (the if would be converted to a cond): `(raise-arguments-error 'intervalo "lower bound greater than upper bound" "lower" l "upper" s)`